# PySpark : How do you use the values in multiple columns to perform some sort of aggregation?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

What i have :

```
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|dotId  |codePp    |status    |
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|dot0001 |Pp3523   |start     |
#|dot0001 |Pp3524   |stop      |
#|dot0020 |Pp3522   |start     |
#|dot0020 |Pp3556   |stop      |
#|dot9999 |Pp3545   |stop      |
#|dot9999 |Pp3523   |start     |
#|dot9999 |Pp3587   |stop      |
#|dot9999 |Pp3567   |start     |
#------------------------------|
```

What i want :

**Instruction**: if status is 'stop' put codePp with '(stop)' else put 'codePp'

```
#+-------+----------------------------------------------+
#|dotId  |codePp                                        |
#+-------+----------------------------------------------+
#|dot0001 |Pp3523, Pp3524(stop)                         |
#|dot0020 |Pp3522, Pp3556(stop)                         |
#|dot9999 |Pp3545(stop), Pp3523, Pp3587(stop), Pp3567   |
#-------------------------------------------------------|
```

But how to wrote it at pyspark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following using a case expression (using `when`) to determine whether to append the status. This was done in a group by/aggregation that used `collect_list` to gather all `codePp` values and `concat_ws` to convert it into a comma separated string.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df =(
    df.groupBy("dotId")
      .agg(
          F.concat_ws(
              ', ',
              F.collect_list(
                  F.concat(
                      F.col("codePp"),
                      F.when(F.col("status")=="stop"),"(stop)")
                  )
              )
          ).alias("codePp")
      )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Apart from a few parenthesis problems, **it works**, thank you.